# How to fix use of unstable library feature 'test': `bench` is a part of custom test frameworks which are unstable

Tags: rust, benchmarking, rust-cargo

While trying to use cargo[benchmark](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-bench.html) feature, it throws error:

```
error: use of unstable library feature 'test': `bench` is a part of custom test frameworks which are unstable

    |
    |     #[bench]
    |       ^^^^^
    |
    = warning: this was previously accepted by the compiler but is being phased out; it will become a hard error in a future release!
    = note: for more information, see issue #64266 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/64266>
    = note: `#[deny(soft_unstable)]` on by default
```

Comment: Well, because it is unstable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steps to fix this issue:

1. compile using nightly version or set nightly to default:

> To compile using nightly version:

```
cargo +nightly bench ...
```

> To set nightly as default:

```
rustup default nightly
```

2. add test feature

To do this, add 2 lines to the top of your root file. (Even above imports)

```
#![feature(test)]
extern crate test;

use...
```

This will allow you to use the `#[bench]` feature.